# How to Alter a Dict's Values in a List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, syntax, list-comprehension

I have a list of of dictionaries and my current list comprehension is *separating* the dictionaries (i.e., creating new dictionaries where they weren't previously).  Here is some example code to help illustrate the problem.

```
list_of_dicts = [{"this": "hi<br>", "that":"bye"}, {"this": "bill", "that":"nye"},{"hello":"kitty<br>", "good bye": "to all of that"}]
```

Thus, as you can see, I have a list whose `len()` is **three**.  Each item is a dictionary that includes two keys and two values.

Here is my list comprehension:

```
list_of_dicts = [{key: val.replace("<br>", " ")} for dic in list_of_dicts for key, val in dic.items()]
```

if you print `len()` of this new line, you will note that I now have **six** dictionaries.  I trust that what I am trying to do -- i.e., replace `"<br>"` in values with one space (`" "`) -- is possible, but I don't know how.

thus far, I've tried every way I know to create a dictionary instead of `{key: val.method()}`. The only thing I have *not* tried is a ternary list comprehension, because I can see it being so long that I would never want it in production code.

Any insight? Can I manipulate the value of some dicts in a list comprehension without compromising the dict's initial structure?

Comment: Why must it be a list comprehension; why not just iterate over the list conventionally?

Comment: it's just preference.  I can read list comprehensions more easily than nested code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for your edit.  my questions are always terribly confusing.  you probably earned me a very rare upvote, so thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary comprehension is being executed six times because your current code is equivalent to this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{"this": "hi<br>", "that":"bye"}, {"this": "bill", "that":"nye"},{"hello":"kitty<br>", "good bye": "to all of that"}]
tmp = []

for dic in list_of_dicts:
    for key, val in dic.items():
        tmp.append({key: val.replace("<br>", " ")})

list_of_dicts = tmp
```

The outer loop will run three times because `list_of_dicts` has three items.  The inner loop will run twice for each iteration of the outer loop because each dictionary in `list_of_dicts` has two items.  In all, this line:

```
tmp.append({key: val.replace("<br>", " ")})
```

will be executed six times.

---

You can fix this problem by simply moving the `for key, val in dic.items()` clause inside the dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> list_of_dicts = [{"this": "hi<br>", "that":"bye"}, {"this": "bill", "that":"nye"},{"hello":"kitty<br>", "good bye": "to all of that"}]
>>> [{key: val.replace("<br>", " ") for key, val in dic.items()} for dic in list_of_dicts]
[{'this': 'hi ', 'that': 'bye'}, {'this': 'bill', 'that': 'nye'}, {'hello': 'kitty ', 'good bye': 'to all of that'}]
>>>
```

Now, the dictionary comprehension will only be executed three times: once per item in `list_of_dicts`.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a nested comprehension

```
list_of_dicts = [dict((key, val.replace("<br>", " "))
                      for key, val in d.iteritems())
                 for d in list_of_dicts]
```

however you're making things more complex than they need to be... What about the simpler:

```
for d in list_of dicts:
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = v.replace("<br>", " ")
```

instead?

Answer (score 2):

In this case the list comprehension can be confusing. I suggest a classical `for` loop:

### source

```
data = [{"this": "hi<br>", "that":"bye"}, {"this": "bill", "that":"nye"},{"hello":"kitty<br>", "good bye": "to all of that"}]

for mydict in data:
    for key,value in mydict.iteritems():
        mydict[key] = value.replace('<br>', '')

print data
```

### output

```
[{'this': 'hi', 'that': 'bye'}, {'this': 'bill', 'that': 'nye'}, {'hello': 'kitty', 'good bye': 'to all of that'}]
```